# How to set ticks location on animate plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ticker

In the code below, The plot don't use the ticks that i defined with MultipleLocator. I don't know why.
I tried to set ticks location in the animate function but it did not work.

Please ! Someone Can tell me how to resolve this problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))


def animate(i):
    f = open('data2.csv', 'r').read()
    lines = f.split('\n')
    x, y = [], []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            a, b = line.split(';')
            x.append(float(a))

        y.append(float(b))
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, y)


animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```